# Error trying getting clock resolution time

Tags: c, time.h

I'm using C and I'm trying to get Clock resolution but I get this value: 0.000000

Here is the code I'm using

```
#include <time.h>
#include<stdio.h>

double duration(struct timespec start, struct timespec end) {
    return end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec
         + ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec ) / (double) 1000000000.0);
}
double getResolution(){
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    do {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    } while (duration(start, end) == 0.0);
    return duration(start, end);
}
    
int main(){
        
    printf("%f",getResolution());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're not printing enough digits. Try `printf("%.16lf", getResolution());` or `printf("%e", getResolution());`

Comment: Comparing floating point is never what you think it is. Especially `while (==)` will usually be broken in subtle ways, as eg. `+0.0` and `-0.0` are not equal, while `n` and `n+1` are (for sufficiently large n). With doubles and floats, stick to `>=`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks it display the correct number now, I see 0.0000001000000000

Comment: You might want to write an own answer, and mark it later.

Comment: Unrelated: `1000000000.0` is already a `double`. You don't need the cast to `double`.

Comment: @Agent_L, `==` is correct here. They are checking if the time changed since the previous call.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to increase the precision in your `printf("%f");`. Using `printf("%.12f");` would probably be enough to show some non-zero decimals.
2. Calculating the floating point duration in the `while` loop may cause the program to actually perform that calculation if the compiler isn't clever enough to figure out that you only need to see if the clock has changed at all. You could just do a `memcmp` to compare `start` and `end` instead.
3. Don't take the `struct timespec`s by value in your `duration` function. Supply pointers to the function instead. It should be cheaper.
4. Use the `clock_getres` function to get the resolution. The runtime value you get with your homebrewed solution depends on what speed the CPU is currently running at etc.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// taking the arguments via pointers:
double duration(const struct timespec* start, const struct timespec* end) {
    return end->tv_sec - start->tv_sec +
           ((end->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0);
}

double getResolution() {
    struct timespec start = {0}, end = {0};

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
    
    do {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);

        // using memcmp below:
    } while (memcmp(&start, &end, sizeof start) == 0);
    
    return duration(&start, &end);
}

int main() {
    struct timespec base = {0}, res;

    // using the proper function to get the resolution:
    clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res);

    // comparing the results:    
    printf("clock_getres  = %.12f\n", duration(&base, &res));
    printf("getResolution = %.12f\n", getResolution());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qWT5eavvx)